# stop layout from rearranging after animation

Tags: android, animation, layout

I use animation in my app. My animation is moving a small layout to a point where its half way out of the screen, that way I want it.

My problem is that when I use `params.setMargins(500, 0, 0, 0); resetButton.setLayoutParams(params);`, the layout rearrange itself and all the views in it are become small and crushed.

I want the layout to stay the way it is despite it being out side of the screen. Is that Possible?

I'll add my code:

```
SetAnimationParameters(true);
        mainLayout.startAnimation(animationSet);
        animationSet.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                mainLayout.clearAnimation();
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mainLayout
                        .getLayoutParams();
                params.setMargins(500, 0, 0, 0);

                mainLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        });
```

and thats where I set the animation parameters:

```
private void SetAnimationParameters(boolean isRight) {
    if (isRight) {
        TAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 500, 0, 0);
    } else {
        TAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(500, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    TAnimation.setDuration(250);
    animationSet = new AnimationSet(false);
    animationSet.setFillAfter(true);
    animationSet.addAnimation(TAnimation);
}
```

As you can see after the animation is done (onAnimationEnd), I am translating the view to where the animation has ended, so it will be usable. But after that (and that is my problem) the layout is rearranged so all the views in it will not be out of the screen by shrinking them and I don't want that. I want the view to keep on being half way out.

Did I manage to be clear?

Comment: why dont you use Translate, Rotate and scaleAnimation instead of setting margin?

Comment: Thats what I did. but at the end of the animation you need the translate the layout so you can interact with what that was beneath it.

Comment: i did not understand, please explain clearly, by images or write full explanation in question, as we can help you.